# Python standalone application failing when launched (macOS)

Tags: python, macos, pyqt, py2app

So I have made this simple Password Manager in Python 3.8 using PyQt5, and I have been using the 'py2app' module to create a standalone application of this program. However, when I execute my app (both from the terminal and the finder), I get a simple popup saying "keysafe Error". My code is executing just fine and has no errors. I can't seem to figure out the problem here. If it helps, I get this message in my macOS logs:

```
Mar 16 10:29:01 my-MacBook-Air com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: Coalition Cache Hit: app<application.org.pythonmac.unspecified.keysafe.5854321.5857989(501)> [78372]
Mar 16 10:29:01 my-MacBook-Air keysafe[16934]: keysafe Error
Mar 16 10:29:02 my-MacBook-Air com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (application.org.pythonmac.unspecified.keysafe.5854321.5857989[16934]): Service exited with abnormal code: 255
```

I have also been using the following terminal commands to generate my standalone application using py2app:

```
cd <path_to_my_python_script>
py2applet --make-setup keysafe.py
python3 setup.py py2app
```

I really can't figure out what to do, and all help is appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

**Update:**
If you go to your application and right-click it in the finder, it will give you a menu option. Then, click `Show Package Contents`. After that, navigate to the `Contents > MacOS` and you will see a `Unix Executable File` of your python script. Run the file, and you can locate what your error is. 
After trying this out, I got an error with problems about the function I had named `exit` in my password manager. I thought that the keyword `exit` might conflict with some sort of MacOS Setting, and changed the function name to `exit_`. After creating another Standalone Application with my updated script, I ran the Unix executable again and got a new error (so the `exit` keyword was fixed). My new error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "{path}/Password Manager/dist/keysafe.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 110, in <module>
    _run()
  File "{path}/keysafe.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 84, in _run
    exec(compile(source, path, "exec"), globals(), globals())
  File "{path}/Password Manager/dist/keysafe.app/Contents/Resources/keysafe.py", line 1, in <module>
    from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "cryptography/fernet.pyc", line 16, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "cryptography/hazmat/primitives/padding.pyc", line 11, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_padding.pyc", line 14, in <module>
  File "cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_padding.pyc", line 10, in __load
  File "imp.pyc", line 342, in load_dynamic
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_cffi_backend'
2021-04-04 10:30:46.115 keysafe[27312:1337934] keysafe Error
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

Comment: Facing same issue while trying to launch an non UI App using launchApplicationAtURL for an UI application on MAC M1 machine, application launches fine most of the time but sometimes it fail with following logs in console
Mar 17 14:03:04 my-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: Coalition Cache Hit: app<application.com.<cname>.<appname>.application.35876229.35876236(501)> [80762]

Comment: I am also on an M1, so it might be something related to that. If I find a solution, I will be sure to post it on this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally was able to find an answer to this question!
The first thing to do is open your `setup.py` file, the default one should look like so:

```
"""
This is a setup.py script generated by py2applet

Usage:
    python setup.py py2app
"""

from setuptools import setup

APP = ['my_program.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

Then, change the `OPTIONS = {}` to include each one of your imports

```
OPTIONS = {'includes': ['cryptography.fernet', 'PyQt5.QtWidgets',
                        'PyQt5.QtGui', 'PyQt5.Qt', 'PyQt5', 'PyQt5.QtCore', '_cffi_backend']}
```

This manually imports your modules, and this should work if you were getting any similar errors!